# Use CultureInfo to get ISO-639 language code

Tags: .net, t-sql, iso

I want to find three-letter ISO 639-2 Language Code for specified LCID in TSQL. I know that I can do that with .NET:

```
public static SqlString GetThreeLetterISO(SqlInt16 lcid) 
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo((int)lcid, true);            
    return ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve that without storing it in table or using custom assembly?
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo` in mscorlib.dll is loaded on SQL Server, so why not?

Comment: Sure, just create a CLR function, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx .

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @shriop :but for CLR function I need to deploy .NET assembly with that function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx